# How can I use the result of a SQL query in another SQL query

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a ticket program in vb.net using MySQL.

What I want is to use the *Statename* that a ticket can have (open/closed/on hold/etc) that I get from query 1, and use it in query 2 to get a list of all *statenames*, with the result of the first query as first item.

I now use 2 queries after each other, but i'm sure it can be done in 1 query.

Query 1:

```
SELECT StateName 
  FROM Tickets t 
  JOIN States s
    ON s.stateID = t.StateID 
 WHERE TicketNumber = & *intTicketNumber*
```

--> Result = "Open"

Query 2:

```
SELECT StateName 
  from States 
 ORDER 
    BY(case when StateName = '" & *StrStateName* & "' then 0 else 1 end)
     , StateName desc
```

The Desired result of the combined query should be:

1. open
2. assigned
3. closed
4. on hold

How Can I combine there 2 queries?
Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can instead make `States` as your Leftmost table and do a `LEFT JOIN` to the Tickets table, on `stateID` and `TicketNumber`. Match the `TicketNumber` in the Join condition, instead of `Where`.
- Making `States` as leftmost table will ensure that all the StateName values will be considered.
- For a particular TicketNumber, `t.StateId` will be `NULL` (post LEFT JOINing), except for one StateName (assigned to the Ticket currently).
- You can them simply sort on the `t.StateId` in Descending order. Ticket's current StateName will appear first in the list and rest of them sorted afterwards.

Try with Left join instead:

```
SELECT s.StateName 
FROM States AS s
LEFT JOIN Tickets AS t 
  ON s.stateID = t.StateID AND 
     t.TicketNumber = $intTicketNumber  -- $intTicketNumber is the input variable
ORDER BY t.StateID DESC, 
         s.StateName DESC
```

Comment: Madhur, thank you very much. Your answer does exactly what I asked!